# Declaring arrays according the user input

Tags: c, arrays, variables, macros, variable-declaration

i'm trying to declare arrays depending on the user input,
consider if user enters 2, then i need to declare 2 arrays.
like :`int case1[10]={},case2[10]={}`,
i tried it using macros *CONCAT* but it didn't worked, so how can we do it?

Comment: Btw, why don't you use `int case[row][col]` and take the `row` value from user so that if user enters `2` you will be having `case[0]` and `case[1]` & so on, except the fact that compiler should supports [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that. Variable declarations are a compile time thing, long before the user gets to interact with the program (at runtime). Macros are also expanded at compile time.

But whenever you have variables named `foo1`, `foo2`, `foo3`, etc., why not just use an array instead? Then you can have `foo[0]`, `foo[1]`, `foo[2]`, and so on.

In your case standard "dynamic array" techniques apply. Either use a variable-length array:

```
int n = get_user_input_somehow();
int arr[n][10];
```

Or use traditional dynamic memory allocation:

```
int n = get_user_input_somehow();
int (*arr)[10] = malloc(n * sizeof *arr);
if (!arr) {
    handle error
}
```

And don't forget to release the memory when you're done:

```
free(arr);
```

In either case you can then use `arr[i][j]` to access elements.